# Why is a quadrilateral insufficient to determine projection/rotation/etc.?

Tags: graphics

Suppose I have a photograph, and four pixel coordinates representing the corners of a rectangular sheet of paper. My goal is to determine the rotation, translation, and projection which maps from the 3D scene containing the sheet of paper on a plane to the 2D image.

I understand there are augmented reality libraries for this, like ARToolkit. However, they all require additional information, namely the parameters of the camera used to take the photograph. My question is, how come having the rectangle's four corner points (in addition to knowing the rectangle's real-world dimensions) is insufficient information to extrapolate 3D information?

It makes sense mathematically since there are so many more unknown variables that bring us from 3D coordinates to 2D screen space, but I'm having a hard time grounding that concept in what I see.

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Does it help for you to count degrees of freedom?

There are **3** degrees of freedom involved in deciding where in space to put the camera. **3** more degrees of freedom to decide how to turn it. **1** degree of freedom to figure out how much the picture it took had been enlarged, and finally **2** degrees of freedom to fix where on the resulting flat image we're looking.

That makes **9** degrees of freedom in total. However, knowing the location of *four* points in the final cropped image gives us only **8** continuously varying variables. Therefore there *must* be a way to slide the camera, zoom level and translation parameters around such that those four points stay in the same place on the screen (while everything else distorts subtly).

If we know even one of these nine parameters, such as the camera's focal length (in pixels!), then there's some hope of getting an unambiguous answer.

Comment: Thanks for the explanation! That definitely makes more sense.